# Parse an undelimited text file using XML schema in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and want to parse a text file containing financial transactions using a defined XML schema.

The application must iterate each line and parse it according to the XmL schema. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse XML and count instances of a particular node attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-to-parse-xml-and-count-instances-of-a-particular-node-attribute)

Comment: is your text file just $ date or something like that and you're trying to scrape that data and put it into your XML schema?